# Getting result from query made by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a PHP function that checks if a given value is in a column of a database. The function takes the argument `$userName` and `$link` where `$userName` will be checked in the `userid` column of the database `$link` is for. Here is what I've got so far:

```
<?php  
/*This function checks to see if the username is already in use  
INPUT: the userName to check for and a link to the database  
OUTPUT: true if there are no other users registered with userName  
*/  
function isUnique($userName, $link)  
{  
    $result = !!mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `userid`  
    FROM `login`  
    WHERE `userid` = \''.$userName.'\''));  
    return $result;  
}  


echo '<html><head><title>testing</title><body>';  
$uName = $_POST['us'];  
$pass = $_POST['pa'];  

//database work  
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "");  
if(!$link)  
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: '.mysql_error());  
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, 'Accounts');  
if(!$db_selected)  
    die('Can\'t use Accounts: '.mysql_error());  
echo '<br />Using Accounts database<br />';  
if(isUnique($uName, $link))  
{  
    echo 'username is unique!<br />';  
}  
else  
{  
    echo 'username is not unique!<br />';  
}  
mysqli_close($link);  

echo '</body></html>';  
?>
```

The page always says that the given username is not unique.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @ROYFinley: If you look real closely, you'll see he's using mysqli :)

Comment: yep, sorry, i am used to seeing it in object style. should have looked closer.

Comment: @Celeritas http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: This is also cross posted [here on another forum](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/273160-problem-with-retrieving-results-from-mysql-query/)

Comment: I posted the question there because, for whatever reason, the solutions here did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isUnique($userName, $link)
{
                $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `userid`
                        FROM `login`
                        WHERE `userid` = \''.$userName.'\''));
                return mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0;
}
```

copied from [phpfreaks](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/273160-problem-with-retrieving-results-from-mysql-query/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function isUnique($userName, $link) {
    return !!mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, "select `userid` from `login` where `userid`='".$userName."'"));
}
```

Since `mysqli_fetch_row` returns `null` if there is no row, and an array if there is one, casting to boolean will tell you if there was a row or not.

Comment: Make sure to comment on it, so you don't get confused 6 months from now!

Comment: Can't say it works. Now the return value is always nothing (i.e. `''`).

Comment: How can the return value be nothing if it's a boolean? Are you sure the query is correct? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Kolink I was mistaking about it being nothing, when I `echo`'d it was always empty but I tested it with an if statement and it is always false. No errors. And no I'm not sure the query is correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the single quotes, double quotes and back tick. I'm not familiar with the rules of how they work in MySQL.

Comment: I got it working, care to explain what !! does cause I ended up not using it.

Comment: `!!` converts whatever comes after it to a boolean.

Comment: I don't know why your solution didn't work but [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/273160-problem-with-retrieving-results-from-mysql-query/) they told me not to use !!. Any case thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userName = mysqli_escape_string($userName); // Or such

"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE userid='$userName'"
```

BTW IMO it's better to `INSERT` and then check for number of inserted rows and error code / msg.
If that's 0 and "...duplicate...", then you know it's in use, and can treat properly.